# Why do I obtain a skewed spectrum from the FFT? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, fft

I try to find the strongest frequency component with Matlab. It works, but if the datapoints and periods are not nicely aligned, I need to zero-pad my data to increase the FFT resolution. So far so good.

The problem is that, when I zero-pad too much, the frequency with the maximal power changes, even if everything is aligned nicely and I would expect a clear result.

This is my MWE:

```
Tmax = 1024;
resolution = 1024;
period = 512;

X = linspace(0,Tmax,resolution);
Y = sin(2*pi*X/period);

% N_fft = 2^12; % still fine, max_period is 512
N_fft = 2^13; % now max_period is 546.1333

F = fft(Y,N_fft);
power = abs(F(1:N_fft/2)).^2;

dt = Tmax/resolution;
freq = (0:N_fft/2-1)/N_fft/dt;

[~, ind] = max(power);
max_period = 1/freq(ind)
```

With zero-padding up to `2^12` everything works fine, but when I zero-pad to `2^13`, I get a wrong result. It seems like too much zero-padding shifts the spectrum, but I doubt it. I rather expect a bug in my code, but I cannot find it. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** It seems like the spectrum is skewed towards the low frequencies. Zero-padding just makes this visible:

Why is my spectrum skewed? Shouldn't it be symmetric?

[image: skewed spectrum]

Comment: I ran your code for exponents 11,12,13,14 and got the following indices for `max(power)` : `inds = 
    p11: 5
    p12: 9
    p13: 16
    p14: 32`   which suggests pretty strongly that you're losing track by one index value.  That should be a strong clue as to what the `fft` is doing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use a better window function!

The long version:

After searching further, I finally found the explanation. Neither is indexing the problem, nor the additional low frequency components added by the zero-padding. The frequency response of the rectangular window, combined with the *negative* frequency components is the culprit. I found out on [this website](http://www.katjaas.nl/FFTwindow/FFTwindow.html) explaining window functions.

I made more plots to explain:

[image: solution to my FFT issue]

**Top:** The frequency response without windowing: *two* delta peaks, one at the positive and one at the negative frequency. I always plotted the positive part, since I didn't expect to need the negative frequency components. **Middle:** The frequency response of the rectangular window function. It is relatively broad, but I didn't care, because I thought I'd have only a single peak. **Bottom:** The frequency response of the zero-padded signal. In time domain, this is the multiplication of window function and sine-wave. In frequency domain, this amounts to the convolution of the frequency response of the window function with the frequency response of the perfect sine. Since there are two peaks, the relatively broad frequency responses of the window *overlap significantly*, leading to a skewed spectrum and therefore a shifted peak.

**The solution:** A way to circumvent this is to use a proper window function, like a Hamming window, to have a much smaller frequency response of the window, leading to less overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graphic explanation of what you're doing wrong (which is mostly a resolution problem). 
EDIT:  this shows the power for each fft data point, mapped to the indices of the 2^14 dataset.  That is, the indices for the 2^13 data numbered 1,2,3 map to 1,3,5 on this graph; the indices for 2^12 data numbered 1,2,3 map to 1,5,9; and so on.

[image: power curves vs. padding] .
You can see that the "true" value should in fact not be 512 -- your indexing is off by 1 or a fraction of 1.

Comment: It is a good practice to fit some low-order curve (say a parabola) to the few points around the maximum, and take the maximum of the fitted curve as your output. This way there is no coupling between the fft grid and the output you read, and your resolution is not limited the way it is now (so you can zero-pad with a lower number of zeros).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is a nice picture, but I am not sure if it backs your conclusion: From the picture it is clearly visible that the peaks of the lower resolutions aren't aligned with the peaks of the higher ones. This means the true maximum with infinite resolution is not at the generating frequency.

Comment: @Edgar  the point of the graph is that you don't have enough resolution, i.e. data points at specific frequencies, to label a data point as the true peak of the spectrum.  That's why Itamar's suggestion to do a parabolic (or similar) fit to find the exact peak is a good idea.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I agree with that, that's why I updated the question. In fact, the maximum of the spectrum is at a different location as the frequency of the generating signal (as soon as I add zero-padding). But if I add more zeros, the interpolation is better, but the location doesn't change anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a bug in your code. It has to do with the properties of the DFT (and thus the FFT, which is merely a fast version of the DFT).

When you zero-pad, you add frequency resolution, particularly on the lower end.

Here you use a sine wave as test, so you are basically convolving a finite length sine with finite sines and cosines (see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform details), which have almost the same or lower frequency.

If you were doing a "proper" fft, i.e. doing integrals from -inf to +inf, even those low frequency components would give you zero coefficients for the FFT, but since you are doing finite sums, the result of those convolutions is not zero and hence the actual computed fourier transform is inaccurate.

Comment: That sounds reasonable that zero-padding adds low frequency components. I think I can even see that if I look at the spectrum, which gets more and more skewed as I add zero-padding.

Comment: Any Idea of how to circumvent this?

Comment: I did more tests and realized: The spectrum _doesn't_ get more skewed with additional zero-padding. It keeps the shape, getting more and more densely sampled.

Comment: Its not that the zero padding adds more low frequency components, it adds more basis functions to the FFT with frequencies near or below your low frequency signal and you have insufficient terms in the sum to cancel out the contributions from these. Consider this: If you have two sines, sin(x) and sin(x+dx) and integrate them from -inf to inf, it should be zero, but if you compute a finite sum or integral, it wont be zero.

Comment: There is actually a way to circumvent this: Use more data.The more unpadded data you have, i.e. the longer the segment is over which you compute the spectrum, the more accurate the low-frequency power estimates will be. Try e.g. Tmax=16*1024, and you will find that now you can have a lot more bins and still be accurate. Also, you wont have this trouble with most real world data, which wont be pure sinusoids.

Comment: In the actual use-case I made this toy problem for, I don't have more data available. :(